# Im trying to Send a random number though a email but i keep getting a error

Tags: python

My code is an email code for a generating number to send via email

```
msg = ('The number is',random.randrange(300,400),'Enjoy')
```

But I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   line 30, in <module>
    server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrs, msg)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\smtplib.py", line 793, in sendmail
    (code, resp) = self.data(msg)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\smtplib.py", line 532, in data
    q = _quote_periods(msg)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\smtplib.py", line 168, in _quote_periods
    return re.sub(br'(?m)^\.', b'..', bindata)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\re.py", line 175, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Comment: You're passing a `tuple` as the `msg`, not a `str`. Why not e.g. `msg = "The number is {}. Enjoy.".format(random.randrange(300, 400))`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to turn `msg` into a string, for example by using the string formatting operator:

```
msg =  'The number is %d. Enjoy!' % random.randrange(300, 400)
```

Currently, `msg` is a tuple.

Answer (score 2):

Your msg is a tuple , you can use `format()` of string to define a msg:

```
>>> import random
>>> msg = ('The number is',random.randrange(300,400),'Enjoy')
>>> print msg
('The number is', 300, 'Enjoy')
>>> msg = 'The number is {0}, Enjoy'.format(random.randrange(300, 400))
>>> msg
'The number is 325, Enjoy'
```